# IPSec MTU DDos attack

Tags: vpn, ssh, ddos, ipsec, packet

I have this configuration:

```
HOST-A <---> GAT-A <---> MiTM <---> GAT-B <---> HOST-B
```

I'm doing a security project on MTU-IPsec vulnerabilities and following [this](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01052994/document) guide of Hal-Inria, I'm able to inject a packet to the `gateway A`, and change the MTU towards `gateway B`. Then, because I set an `MTU` lower than 552 i expect to be set on minimum for IPv4: `576 bytes`.

I expect this to impact all the hosts behind gateway A, in this way:

*upon receiving this ICMP PTB packet, the host computes the PMTU to use :PMTU=max(MTU-ICMP PTB,MTUconfig.) = 552. Therefore the TCP segments are fragmented (remember that the host sets the DF bit to be sure that no fragmentation appears later on in the network for performance reasons). Nevertheless, instead of creating 514 byte packets, as requested by the gateway, the host generates 500 + 52 = 552 bytepackets (step 5). Since it remains too large, they are dropped by the gateway and this latter replies with ICMP PTB packets. After 2 minutes of failures, the ssh server initiates a half-close(FIN/ACK exchange) (but the other side of the TCP connection curiously remains open). To conclude, the TCP connection is completely blocked and the DoS is successful.*

However when i try to `ssh Host B` and to transfer larger bulk of data,the `ESP` packets over ssh are now fragmented. With ssh, the DF bit is set, why this happens, shouldn't the host A send packets with size corresponding to proper MTU? What am I missing here?